# Problems with Amazon MSK default configuration and publishing with transactions

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions, aws-msk

Recently we have started doing some testing of our Kafka connectors to MSK, Amazon's managed Kafka service.  Publishing records seem to work fine however *not* when transactions are enabled.

Our cluster consists of 2 brokers (because we have 2 zones) using the default MSK configuration.  We are creating our Java Kafka producer using the following properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=x.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9094,y.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9094
client.id=kafkautil
max.block.ms=5000
request.timeout.ms=5000
security.protocol=SSL
transactional.id=transactions
```

However when the producer was started with the `transactional.id` setting which enables transactions, the `initTransactions()` method hangs:

```
producer = new KafkaProducer<Object, Object>(kafkaProperties);
if (kafkaProperties.containsKey(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG)) {
    // this hangs
    producer.initTransactions();
}
```

Looking at the log output we see streams of the following, and it didn't seem like it ever timed out.

```
TransactionManager - Enqueuing transactional request (type=FindCoordinatorRequest,
    coordinatorKey=y, coordinatorType=TRANSACTION)
TransactionManager - Request (type=FindCoordinatorRequest, coordinatorKey=y,
    coordinatorType=TRANSACTION) dequeued for sending
NetworkClient - Found least loaded node z:9094 (id: -2 rack: null) connected with no
    in-flight requests
Sender - Sending transactional request (type=FindCoordinatorRequest, coordinatorKey=y,
    coordinatorType=TRANSACTION) to node z (id: -2 rack: null)
NetworkClient - Sending FIND_COORDINATOR {coordinator_key=y,coordinator_type=1} with
    correlation id 424 to node -2
NetworkClient - Completed receive from node -2 for FIND_COORDINATOR with
    correlation id 424, received {throttle_time_ms=0,error_code=15,error_message=null,
    coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}}
TransactionManager LogContext.java:129 - Received transactional response
    FindCoordinatorResponse(throttleTimeMs=0, errorMessage='null', 
    error=COORDINATOR_NOT_AVAILABLE, node=:-1 (id: -1 rack: null)) for request
    (type=FindCoordinatorRequest, coordinatorKey=xxx, coordinatorType=TRANSACTION)
```

As far as I can determine, the broker *is* available and each of the hosts in the `bootstrap.servers` property are available.  If I connect to each of them and publish without transactions then it works.

Any idea what we are missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However when the producer was started with the transactional.id setting which enables transactions, the initTransactions() method hangs:

This turned out to a problem with the default AWS MSK properties and the number of brokers.  If you create a Kafka cluster with less than 3 brokers, the following settings will need to be adjusted.

The following settings should be set (I think) to the number of brokers:

| Property | Kafka Default | AWS Default | Should Be (1) | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default.replication.factor | 1 | 3 | 2 | Default replication factors for automatically created topics. |
| min.insync.replicas | 1 | 2 | 2 | Minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write for the write to be considered successful |
| offsets.topic. replication.factor | 3 | 3 | 2 | Internal topic that shares offsets on topics. |
| transaction.state.log. replication.factor | 3 | 3 | 2 | Replication factor for the transaction topic. |

Here's the [Kafka docs on broker properties](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs).

(1) Because we have 2 brokers, we ended up with:

```
default.replication.factor=2
min.insync.replicas=2
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=2
```

This seemed to resolve the issue.  IMHO this is a real problem with the AWS MSK and the default configuration.  They need to auto-generate the default configuration and tune it depending on the number of brokers in the cluster.

Comment: With the configuration that you posted, if one of the brokers goes down and your producers are using ack=:all (-1), writes won't be accepted right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the write to the broker that is up won't be accepted @bilby91.  You may have to turn on transactions to get that lever of cluster consistency.